# NetworkEngineering syntax highlighting

Tags: support, editing, formatting

Please turn on [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints) on NetworkEngineering.SE so questions like these are more readable...

- [Discussion about Python OpenFlow Controller](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6969/decoding-packets-in-an-openflow-ryu-switch)
- [answer which requires TCL code](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7429/rate-limit-specific-cisco-isr-syslog-messages)